# Initial job has not accepted any resources vs Java Heap Space Standalone Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I'm implementing an Apache Spark RDD but I keep getting this error:

`Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

I'm aware that I have a huge amount of data (10gb+) but I should be able to allocate enough resources for my app to run.

Is there any way to know the size of my RDD and then allocate the necessary resources? What are the advised configs for a standalone app? Since I'm only using my computer (16GB RAM, 100GB on disk left) should I use 8 cores or 4?

Kind regards

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 spark-submit --master spark://luiscosta:7077 --driver-cores 4 --driver-memory 70g --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 50g --executor-cores 4 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize="0"  spark_preprocessing.py
```

**EDIT**

I managed to fix the `initial job` error. However after running for 45 minutes I ran out of heap space.

Is there any way to find a balance so I have enough resources and heap space? I basically decreased the driver memory and increased the number of executors. I really don't understand how this solved my resources problem , nor why my app runs out of heap space.

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 spark-submit --master spark://luiscosta:7077 --driver-cores 4 --driver-memory 8g --num-executors 3 --executor-memory 14G --executor-cores 4 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize="0"  spark_preprocessing.py
```

Comment: [One of possible reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40854231/6910411)

Comment: I edited my question. I'm intrigued

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

As far as I understood, `Initial job has not accepted any resources` errors are associated with `spark.executor-memory` and `Java Heap Space` with `spark.driver.memory`. I tuned those parameters and everything is running fine.